# ServletContext Attribute is null when accessing it via restful web service in jersey implementation

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I have a Java MVC application with a single controller. The database is initialized in servlet context listener class. I am passing the database object as a servlet context attribute to the controller servlet and webservice class. In controller servlet the "db" attribute is working fine but in web service class I am getting null and illegal state exception.

Error stacktrace -

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They
are: 
1. java.lang.NullPointerException
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on 
com.home.mystorywriter.UserWS

org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:    388)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:    341)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:    228)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.home.mystorywriter.UserWS.<init>(UserWS.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

webservice class

```
package com.home.mystorywriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

@Path("/users")

public class UserWS {

@Context
 private HttpServletRequest req;
 private HttpServletResponse res;
 private ServletContext context ;
 DAOdb db = (DAOdb)req.getServletContext().getAttribute("db");

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("allUsers")
public String getAllUsers() {
List<Profile> userlist = db.getProfileListOfAllUsers();
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 String jsonUsers = gson.toJson(userlist);
 return jsonUsers;
 }

 }
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"      
si:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
<listener>
    <description>MyServletContextListener</description>
    <listener-  
      class>com.home.mystorywriter.MyServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>StoryServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.home.mystorywriter.StoryServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>com.home.mystorywriter</param-value>
</init-param>
 <init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>StoryServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/StoryServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>login.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: You misidentified the problem. It's not the attribute that is null. It's `req` which is null at that point. You're basically attempting to access it before it's being injected.

Comment: Thank you for guiding in the right context ! Yes the injection happens at the resource level. Below code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

@Context injection happens inside the web service class or class method. Below code is working fine.

```
@Path("/users")

public class UserWS {
private ServletContext context ;
DAOdb db;
public UserWS() {
System.out.println("Inside Constructor " + context); 
}
@Context
public void setServletContext(ServletContext context) {
System.out.println("servlet context set here");
this.context = context;
db = (DAOdb)context.getAttribute("db");
}
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/allUsers")
public String getAllUsers() {
System.out.println("Inside get method:"+ context);
System.out.println("db value"+ db);
Profile userlist = db.getProfileWithoutPic();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonUsers = gson.toJson(userlist);
return jsonUsers;
}
}
```